# await doesnt work on nodejs project as expected

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, async-await

Good day.

Im working on a express project and havent been ables to fully understan how async functions an promises work. This is my project structure

-controllers
--userController.js
-services
--paymentService.js

payment service is the implementation of a third-party payment tool, and it defines a method im using like this

```
const pay = async(data) => {
    service.pay()
        .then(function(response){
            return response;
        }).catch(function(err)){
             console.log(err);
        });
}
```

im calling this method from my userController

```
let payUser = async(req, res) => {

    const response = await paymentService.pay(req.data);
    if(response) {
        res.send(response)
    }
}
```

but response is always undefined, it doesnt wait as i thought it shoudl do because of the "await" keyword.

How does this exactly works? what am i doing wrong if i want to make it wait till the response is returned?

Comment: You don't return anything from your `pay` function, so there's nothing to `await`.

Comment: the pay function could itself be rewritten using try/catch/finally and await, since you bothered to declare it as async... that might clarify things for you, or you could just return the promise chain

Comment: but when im defining the "then()" function on the service call, it should wait that the services completes the promise, and then he return the response and the userController awaits until this happens, shouldnt work like that?

Comment: add a return before 'service.pay' so far the pay function returns nothing (so there is nothing to await)

Comment: You should edit the title of your question to more accurately describe your issue, which is not that the `await` keyword doesn't work as expected in your Node.js project, but that an async function you wrote is returning `undefined` every time, even if you await it.

Comment: Note that even though OP's problem is common, and other Stack Overflow questions exist asking why the returned value of an async function is always `undefined`, I think this question should not be closed as a duplicate because OP's root cause (lack of `return`) is different than the existing questions and contains a much better minimal reproduction of the problem than the existing questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue in your code for the `pay` function:

```js
const pay = async(data) => {
    service.pay()
        .then(function(response){
            return response;
        }).catch(function(err)){
             console.log(err);
        });
}
```

You don't return anything. You just run `service.pay()`. Therefore, the signature of the function `pay` (declared on the first line) is a function that returns a promise, but the return type is `Promise<void>`, not `Promise<YourData>`. This causes it to always return `undefined`, even when called with `await`, like in your complete example code.

I notice you have the code `return response;` inside the "then" callback. This may mean you intended for that data to be returned to the caller of `pay` (not `service.pay`) when the data was ready. To do this, should rewrite your `pay` function in one of two ways:

1. Replace `service.pay ...` with `return service.pay ...` so that the promise returned by `service.pay` is actually returned to the caller of `pay`.
2. Rewrite it so that you remove the "then" callback and replace `service.pay ...` with `return await service.pay ...`. You've already put in the work to design `pay` as an async function, so you can now use `await` inside it, which often makes this kind of code more straightforward to write and read later on.